# Using JavaScript to change the page your form is sent to

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Hey Guys I have a applicate website that has a selection box to chose what store you would like to apply for. I can not figure out how to use the selection box to send the form to another PHP page. Right now when you click submit on the forum it sends it to a php page that emails the form to the correct store. I need to be able to send it to another store if they change the store that they are applying for. I know basic javascript. Please let me know where I can find this answer.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if my code didn't make sense or work as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var option = document.getElementById("clicked");
window.location="nextpagename";
```

Comment: Your intentions appear to be in the right place here but unfortunately this would not apply to a form submission, there's no event handler and you have an extra period in your first line.  I'd recommend deleting to avoid downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Give the selection-box the attribute `data-send_to="some_page"`, and then use this JS code:

```
document.querySelector(".selection_box").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('form').action = this.getAttribute('data-send_to') + '.php';
};
```

Also don't forget to give the form the same id as in the JS code (right now it's simply `form`).

Answer (score 0):

### Change when submitted.

In the **Javascript** below, you would change `FORMNAME` to the name of your form and `SELECTOR` to the name of the selector used inside the form.

```
document.forms.FORMNAME.onsubmit = function (event) {
    var e = event || window.event,
        form = e.currentTarget || e.sourceElement;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.action === "") return false;  // Verify selection made
    form.action = form.SELECTOR.value;
    form.submit();
};
```

Your **HTML** should resemble this (to your page's specs of course):

```
<form name="FORMNAME" action="" method="post">
    <select name="SELECTOR" id="SELECTOR">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Choose destination store---</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

## [See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/xp2vt/)

*PS - I believe you can use Daniel's answer just as well, mine is simply a way to avoid dealing with it until submission actually occurs, his is instantly.  Cheers.*